# How to express a system of equations in terms of another variable

Tags: python, sympy

I want to solve a system of equations symbolically such as `A = ax + by` and `B = cx + dy`, for `x` and `y` explicitly on sympy.

I tried the solve function of sympy as
`solve([A, B], [x, y])`, but isn't working. It's returning an empty list, `[]`.

How can I solve it using sympy?

This is the actual equation I'm trying to solve:

```
from sympy import*
i,j,phi, p, e_phi, e_rho =     symbols(r'\hat{i} \hat{j} \phi \rho e_\phi     e_\rho')
e_rho = cos(phi)*i + sin(phi)*j
e_phi = -p*sin(phi)*i + p*cos(phi)*j
solve([e_rho,e_phi], [i,j])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sadly, Stack Overflow doesn't support Mathjax like the math sites do. You'll have to use any of the various online LaTeX generators out there and post the resulting image here, if you want to display equations.

Comment: Also, please review [ask]. "It's not working" is not a specific issue. What happens, and how does it differ from what you want? If you get an error, make sure to include it, along with its full stack trace.

Comment: I'm not getting an error of that short. I want to slove a system like say A=  M*x+d and B = F*y + g for x and y.

Comment: You should still specify what your code is currently doing -- what result you get.

Comment: I'm only getting an empty array [], that's it.

Comment: Okay, so [edit] your question to include that. Also, if your question can be effectively asked about equations as simple as those, it would be best to do so, rather than using more complex equations that don't display legibly here.

Comment: Ok I understand. Sorry never posted on overflow before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what version of SymPy you're using but I just tried with the latest version and I get an answer:

```
In [4]: from sympy import*
   ...: i,j,phi, p, e_phi, e_rho =     symbols(r'i j phi rho e_phi e_rho')
   ...: e_rho = cos(phi)*i + sin(phi)*j
   ...: e_phi = -p*sin(phi)*i + p*cos(phi)*j
   ...: solve([e_rho,e_phi], [i,j])
Out[4]: {i: 0, j: 0}
```

That's the correct answer to your equations (provided `rho` is nonzero):

```
In [5]: e_rho
Out[5]: i⋅cos(φ) + j⋅sin(φ)

In [6]: e_phi
Out[6]: -i⋅ρ⋅sin(φ) + j⋅ρ⋅cos(φ)
```

If you meant to solve for `e_rho` and `e_phi` to be equal to something other than zero then you should include a right hand side either by subtracting it from the expressions or by using `Eq`:

```
In [2]: A, B = symbols('A, B')

In [3]: solve([Eq(e_rho, A), Eq(e_phi, B)], [i, j])
Out[3]: 
⎧         A⋅ρ⋅cos(φ)               B⋅sin(φ)                 A⋅ρ⋅sin(φ)               B⋅cos(φ)      ⎫
⎪i: ───────────────────── - ─────────────────────, j: ───────────────────── + ─────────────────────⎪
⎨        2           2           2           2             2           2           2           2   ⎬
⎪   ρ⋅sin (φ) + ρ⋅cos (φ)   ρ⋅sin (φ) + ρ⋅cos (φ)     ρ⋅sin (φ) + ρ⋅cos (φ)   ρ⋅sin (φ) + ρ⋅cos (φ)⎪
⎩                                                                                                  ⎭

In [4]: solve([Eq(e_rho, A), Eq(e_phi, B)], [i, j], simplify=True)
Out[4]: 
⎧              B⋅sin(φ)                B⋅cos(φ)⎫
⎨i: A⋅cos(φ) - ────────, j: A⋅sin(φ) + ────────⎬
⎩                 ρ                       ρ    ⎭
```

Again that's the correct answer (assuming `rho != 0`).